# Azure table continuation token and transactions

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When you make a query to a table (same parition key) where you have 5000 items, how is going with the continuation token and transactions? I mean azure will return first 1000 items and a continuation token (that's 1 transcation right?) when you go back with the continuation token to get the next 1000 (and so on for 5 times 1000 x 5 =5000) is that counted as another transaction ? (I guess yes)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Each time you use the next continuation token, you are sending another request to the service for the next segment of data. Note that the number of entities returned in each segment is not necessarily 1000. Depending on how your data is structured and the specific query, you may sometimes get smaller sets of data.